# Bootstrap Responsive Button Group Justified

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In twitter bootstrap 3, there is a component prepared name **button group justified**.
URL: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified

Is there any way we could make `.btn-group.btn-group-justified` responsive friendly if we have more buttons? Maybe we can put it to 2 rows without using `display: block` and retaining its `display: table-cell` so that it could stay vertically align middle?

[image]

Is there built in classes that bootstrap prepared? since they prepared this Button Group Justified css component, dont they have anything to make it responsive friendly if there are many buttons with longer words as text?

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kHW3V/

Comment: you can do this by js, or media queries to this. Please add a fiddle and we can help

Comment: @nol so there is no built in classes that bootstrap prepared? since they prepared this Button Group Justified css component, dont they have anything to make it responsive friendly if there are many buttons with longer words as text? heres my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kHW3V/

Comment: This should not have been down voted.  He has code and an example picture for reference.

Answer (score 2):

well yes if you used regular button groups like this its already responsive

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Text</button>
</div>
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kHW3V/1/)

if you must have the justified one let me know!

Comment: I would really want the Button Group Justified effect

Comment: easiest would be to remove justified if window is resized with jquery

Comment: unfortunately the grouping kinda looks like crap when forced to multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

Using https://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified worked for me

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
   <li><a role="button" class="btn btn-default" href="/mypage1"><img src="/images/myimage1.png" height="32" alt="myimage1"></a></li>
   <li><a role="button" class="btn btn-default" href="/mypage2"><img src="/images/myimage2.png" height="32" alt="myimage2"></a></li>
   <li><a role="button" class="btn btn-default" href="/mypage3"><img src="/images/myimage3.png" height="32" alt="myimage3"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this style for all `.btn` inside `.btn-group-justified`.

```
.btn-group-justified > .btn {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```