# How to create a justified menu, which stacks on mobile with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a justified button group with 6 buttons.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified

it looks great, but on mobile i'd like to make it stack to basically become a vertical button group that is `btn-block`!

Is there a cool way to accomplish this? must i create both, and hide/show on different sizes?

Comment: How is this related to flexbox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Responsive Button Group Justified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118144/bootstrap-responsive-button-group-justified)

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your own responsive CSS, which overwrites Bootstrap's style for mobile view.

[See this sample on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/memRZR)

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .btn-group-justified-responsive > .btn,
  .btn-group-justified-responsive > .btn-group {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }

  .btn-group-justified-responsive > .btn-group > .btn {
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .btn-group-justified-responsive > .btn-group:not(:last-child) > .btn {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .btn-group-justified-responsive > .btn-group:first-child > .btn:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px !important;
  }
  .btn-group-justified-responsive > .btn-group:first-child > .btn:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px !important;
  }
  .btn-group-justified-responsive > .btn-group:last-child > .btn:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px !important;
  }
  .btn-group-justified-responsive > .btn-group:last-child > .btn:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px !important;
  }
}
```